# ASP.NET MVC2 - Dynamic Page Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic

I am kind of new to the world of ASP.NET (especially MVC), I am trying to build up a page based on the configuration below:

```
   <headInput>
    <defaultColumns>
      <column name="Shift" validation="" unit="" required="" />
      <column name="Level" validation="" unit="" required="" />
      <column name="Value" validation="" unit="" required="" />
      <column name="Time" validation="" unit="" required="" />
    </defaultColumns>
    <additionalCols1>
      <column name="Rate" validation="" unit="" required="" />
    </additionalCols1>
    <additionalCols2>
      <column name="Online" validation="" unit="" required="" />
      <column name="Type" validation="" unit="" required="" />
    </additionalCols2>
   </headInput>
```

I have been trying to understand on how I can use the above configuration to generate labels as columns and then generate the row with data in columns.

I tried looking at many examples but haven't been able to figure out if it is even possible or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do or what schema you're using in the example above, but my feeling is that you should be using HTML tables for this:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html

Tables are defined in rows, not columns,  first with the heading row ( then the data rows  then the table data .

Also look at the colspan attribute and the rowspan attribute which I think you'll need for this - lets columns span more than one row and rows span more than one column.

Also if you're learning MVC why are you using a 2 year old version??  MVC3 was released over a year ago and MVC 4 is in beta with a go-live license.  We're using MVC 4 to develop a web based stock trading application and its solid as a rock.

There's an example of building an HTML table using MVC at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/displaying-a-table-of-database-data-cs (scroll to the bottom to see the MVC view)  Its basically HTML with some server tags for pulling the data from the model.  That's how MVC is - very different from webforms where you'd have server controls generating HTML for you.

Comment: well i can probably do it in plain html and asp.net web forms. But I thought of using the MVC and see how much difference does it make. What I am trying to achieve is based on the columns in the configuration file, I would like to generate the Labels in the View dynamically rather than strongly typed.

Comment: You're not understanding MVC..... MVC basically HTML with server tags <%= Model.Data1 %> to fill in the server generated data.  But its basically structured around HTML.  Webforms on the other hand generates HTML from server controls - MVC is very different.

Comment: thanks for your example, that made me understand much better.

Comment: No probs....  I'd recommend using MVC 3 at least though... It introduced a much simpler server view language called Razor which has pretty much become the standard.  Here's a good cheat sheet to show the syntax differences http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to generate HTML based on the XML input. You can use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) to do that.

Your MVC model should provide the XML and the View should use the XSLT to convert it to the HTML

here are few links which might be helpful -

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/xml/converting-xml-to-html-using-xsl.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20210301191904/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/081300-2.shtml